# Is it possible to boot Slax from a CD on a Samsung laptop running Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, slax

Is it possible to boot Slax from a CD on a Samsung laptop running Windows 7?

All the usual things they tell you to try don't work at all. It's not possible to edit boot options in a useful way. When I'm booted in Windows 7, Windows can recognise the CD but not the Slax OS on it. Windows thinks it's a blank CD. Yet I know the CD's OK because I can boot my Mac from it easily. I've also had the identical Slax iso running on the Mac in Virtualbox (slower than slow but it does work).

Is there some Windows software I can get that would help with the boot options?

Is there something I can do (probably have to be on the Mac) to the permissions on the CD that would help?

Any other ideas?

Extra information:

Samsung NP305U1A

Windows 7 Home Premium

External optical drive (unbranded) — the laptop hasn't got an internal one.

Iso burned on the Mac (running Lion) using Simply Burns.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Burns is  not the best option for that.

Try either

> Transmac

or

> Rufus

or  use

> dd from your Mac Terminal

For  Mac Terminal  route: i.e.

> sudo dd if=~/Desktop/SlaxOS.iso of=/dev/rdisk3s2 bs=1m

(can be up to bs=8M (without major  risk of  a corrupt  write, as well if  its a custom larger than normal Slax ISO)

---

For a more "teach me"  writeup  read this article from  OSXDaily [Make a Bootable ISO USB on Mac](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/05/copy-iso-to-usb-drive-mac-os-x-command/)

Answer (score 0):

If the CD is bad, try making a [Slax live USB](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/all-in-one-usb-slaxzip/). There'll be fewer errors that way. Use the Universal USB Installer application to make the Slax live USB, as it can be used to install the latest version.